Can a Live Share guest use GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio Code?
During a Visual Studio Code Live Share session, the host (who initiated the live share session) can use GitHub Copilot as normal. The only caveat seems to be that the guest doesn't see Copilot suggestions until the host accepts them.
But can a VS Code Live Share guest use GitHub Copilot as well?
And if so, who needs to be logged into their GitHub account (with an active Copilot subscription) in order for the guest to use Copilot -- the host or the guest?

This question is clearly about a feature within an IDE, making it on-topic/about programming. I'm not sure why it was ever close voted for that reason.
